# Regular expression to find unknown acronyms

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation, acronym

I need a regular expression that will pick out lines with ALL CAPS or unknown acronyms.

ie: something like

```
/[A-Z]{2,}/
```

combined with

```
/(?!USA|UK|TLA)/
```

Comment: What do you mean by __unknown__ acronyms?

Comment: I want to be able to include a list of known/acceptable acronyms in the regex and have the regex skip those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
\b(?!(?:USA|UK|TLA)\b)[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

See it [here on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/24UKZigl28)

`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to ensure that it will find complete words.